# recompile ffmpeg with libmp3lame

Tags: ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg using yum install in my centos.Now i want to recompile it with 'libmp3lame'.Is possible a recompilation of the installed ffmpeg or i want to remove ffmpeg and reinstall.

suggestion is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike AAC and some other audio formats, FFmpeg does not have a native MP3 encoder, so you have to use a supported external encoding library such as libmp3lame. You have several options if your `ffmpeg` is not configured with `--enable-libmp3lame`:

### Download an already compiled binary

[Download `ffmpeg` for Linux](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). This is an already compiled binary. This is the easiest solution.

See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to Windows and OS X builds.

### Compile `ffmpeg`

Follow a non-invasive step-by-step guide to [Compile FFmpeg on CentOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos). If you can copy and paste you can compile.

### Pipe to `lame`

```
ffmpeg -i input -f wav - | lame - output.mp3
```

I do not consider this to be a practical solution but it may be useful to some.

### Use a different format

If you don't require MP3 you can use AAC or some other audio format that has native encoding support.